# Tiltle of a big table in overleaf

Tags: tables, rotating, overleaf, adjustbox

I am using overleaf latex website for my thesis. I am trying to write a title above a  table; I have tried different way but I do not know how. Would you please help!

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{uthesis-v12}  %---> DO NOT ALTER THIS COMMAND
  \usepackage{graphicx} %---> %---> %---> DO NOT ALTER THIS COMMAND
  \usepackage{eurosym}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage{amsthm}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{color}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{float}
  \usepackage{placeins}
  \usepackage{subfigure}
  \usepackage{indentfirst}
  \usepackage{bm}
  \usepackage{tabularx}
  \usepackage[space]{grffile}
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \usepackage{booktab}
  \usepackage{arydshln}
  \usepackage{array}
  \usepackage{tabu}
  \usepackage{rotating}
  \usepackage{afterpage}
  \usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}
  \usepackage{epstopdf}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
  \usepackage{subcaption}
  \usepackage{capt-of}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
  \usepackage{float}
  \usepackage{perpage}
  \usepackage{adjustbox}
  \usepackage{blindtext}
  \usepackage{mwe}
  \usepackage{rotating}% http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating

        \begin{document}
        \begin{center}
        \begin{adjustbox}{width=1.4\textwidth, rotate=90,center}
        \begin{tabular}{c| c| c| c| c| c| c| c| c| c|c| c| c| c| c| c| c|  c| c| c| c|  c c| }
        \hline
        \multirow{}{Sample size} 
                             & \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{ Step 1 } &       \multicolumn{10}{|c|}{ Step 2} & \multicolumn{5}{|c}{ Relative Frequency} \\
                             \cline{2-22} 
                             & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ ${\hat{\beta_{0}}}$} 
                             & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ ${\hat{\beta_{1}}}$} 
                             & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{ ${\hat{\beta_{2}}}$} 

                             & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ ${\hat{\phi}_{AIC}}$} 
                             & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ ${\hat{\phi}_{AICc}}$} 
                             & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ ${\hat{\phi}_{BIC}}$} 
                             & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ ${\hat{\phi}_{LASSO}}$} 
                             & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{ ${\hat{\phi}_{AdLASSO}}$}

                             & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ Information Criteria } 
                             & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{ Regularization Methods }\\
                             \cline{2-22}
                             &  Mean & SD & Mean & SD  & Mean  & SD 
                             & Mean & SD  & Mean & SD & Mean & SD & Mean & SD & Mean & SD 
                             & AIC & AICc & BIC & LASSO & AdLASSO \\
        \hline
                 ${N=200}$ 
                 %beta0 
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$  
                 %phi1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi3
                 & ${}$ & ${}$
                 %phi4
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi5
                 & ${}$ & ${}$                      
                 %aic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %aicc
                 & ${}$ 
                 %bic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %lasso
                 & ${}$ 
                 %adlasso
                 & ${}$\\
        \hline
                 ${N=400}$ 
                 %beta0 
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$  
                 %phi1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi3
                 & ${}$ & ${}$
                 %phi4
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi5
                 & ${}$ & ${}$         
                 %aic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %aicc
                 & ${}$ 
                 %bic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %lasso
                 & ${}$ 
                 %adlasso
                 & ${}$\\
        \hline
                 ${N=600}$ 
                 %beta0 
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$  
                 %phi1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi3
                 & ${}$ & ${}$
                 %phi4
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi5
                 & ${}$ & ${}$         
                 %aic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %aicc
                 & ${}$ 
                 %bic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %lasso
                 & ${}$ 
                 %adlasso
                 & ${}$\\
        \hline
                 ${N=800}$ 
                 %beta0 
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$  
                 %phi1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi3
                 & ${}$ & ${}$
                 %phi4
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi5
                 & ${}$ & ${}$         
                 %aic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %aicc
                 & ${}$ 
                 %bic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %lasso
                 & ${}$ 
                 %adlasso
                 & ${}$\\
        \hline
                 ${N=1000}$ 
                 %beta0 
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$  
                 %phi1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi3
                 & ${}$ & ${}$
                 %phi4
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi5
                 & ${}$ & ${}$         
                 %aic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %aicc
                 & ${}$ 
                 %bic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %lasso
                 & ${}$ 
                 %adlasso
                 & ${}$\\
       \hline
                 ${N=1200}$ 
                 %beta0 
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$  
                 %phi1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi3
                 & ${}$ & ${}$
                 %phi4
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi5
                 & ${}$ & ${}$         
                 %aic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %aicc
                 & ${}$ 
                 %bic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %lasso
                 & ${}$ 
                 %adlasso
                 & ${}$\\
        \hline
                  ${N=1400}$ 
                 %beta0 
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$  
                 %phi1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi3
                 & ${}$ & ${}$
                 %phi4
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi5
                 & ${}$ & ${}$   
                 %aic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %aicc
                 & ${}$ 
                 %bic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %lasso
                 & ${}$ 
                 %adlasso
                 & ${}$\\
        \hline
                 ${N=1600}$ 
                 %beta0 
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$  
                 %phi1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi3
                 & ${}$ & ${}$
                 %phi4
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi5
                 & ${}$ & ${}$         
                 %aic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %aicc
                 & ${}$ 
                 %bic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %lasso
                 & ${}$ 
                 %adlasso
                 & ${}$\\
        \hline
                  ${N=1800}$ 
                 %beta0 
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$  
                 %phi1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi3
                 & ${0}$ & ${}$
                 %phi4
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi5
                 & ${}$ & ${}$         
                 %aic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %aicc
                 & ${}$ 
                 %bic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %lasso
                 & ${}$ 
                 %adlasso
                 & ${}$\\
        \hline
                 ${N=2000}$ 
                 %beta0 
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %beta2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$  
                 %phi1
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi2
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi3
                 & ${}$ & ${}$
                 %phi4
                 & ${}$ & ${}$ 
                 %phi5
                 & ${}$ & ${}$         
                 %aic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %aicc
                 & ${}$ 
                 %bic
                 & ${}$ 
                 %lasso
                 & ${}$ 
                 %adlasso
                 & ${}$\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \end{adjustbox}
        \end{center}  
        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please make the code compilable (A begin and end document would be nice). And please reduce the used packages to the ones needed.

Comment: off-topic: (i) it is sufficient to load each package ones, so remove all double or more times loaded (ii) the package `hyperref` had to be loaded last. On -topic:  after `\begin{table}` add `\caption{ <caption text>}`.

Answer (score 1):

Overleaf has nothing with caption. It is only (remote) editor ...

I would write your table on the following way:

- for rotating of table use `sidewaystable` defined in the`rotating` package and not `adjustbox`
- for table caption use standard caption `\caption`
- remove `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}
- use smaller font: `\footnotesize`
- instead of `tabular` use `tabular*`
- left calculation of `\tabcolsep` (distances between cells content and its borders) to macro `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`

Considering aforementioned and use only to your problem relevant packages, MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%{uthesis-v12}  % i do not have your document class
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}% http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \caption{My very wide rotated table}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                             *{21}{>{$}c<{$}|} >{$}c<{$}}
    \hline
\multirow{3}{3em}{\centering Sample size}
    & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{ Step 1 } 
        & \multicolumn{10}{c|}{ Step 2} 
            & \multicolumn{5}{c}{ Relative Frequency} \\
    \cline{2-22}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ ${\hat{\beta_{0}}}$}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ ${\hat{\beta_{1}}}$}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ ${\hat{\beta_{2}}}$}
                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ ${\hat{\phi}_{AIC}}$}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ ${\hat{\phi}_{AICc}}$}
                        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ ${\hat{\phi}_{BIC}}$}
                            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ ${\hat{\phi}_{LASSO}}$}
                                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ ${\hat{\phi}_{AdLASSO}}$}
                                    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\makecell{Information\\ Criteria}}
                                        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Regularization\\ Methods}}      \\
    \cline{2-22}
    & \text{Mean} & \text{SD}   & \text{Mean} & \text{SD}   & \text{Mean}  & \text{SD}
    & \text{Mean} & \text{SD}   & \text{Mean} & \text{SD}   & \text{Mean}  & \text{SD}  
        & \text{Mean}  & \text{SD}  & \text{Mean}  & \text{SD}
    & \text{AIC}  & \text{AICc} & \text{BIC} & \text{LASSO} & \text{AdLASSO}                \\
    \hline
N=200   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    \hline
N=400   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    \hline
N=600   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular*}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @ALRADDADI,  I haven't your document class, is the result with it similar to what is obtained at use of `article`? If it so, than you can consider to accept answer (by clicking on check mark at top left side of the answer) ...